# Why is function with useless isolated `static` considered impure?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, category-theory

In Wikipedia article on [Pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), there is an example of impure function like this:

```
void f() {
  static int x = 0;
  ++x;
}
```

With the remark of "because of mutation of a local static variable".

I wonder why is it impure? It's from unit type to unit type, so it always returns the same result for same input. And it has no side effects, because even despite it has `static int` variable, it's unobservable by any other function than this `f()`, so there is no observable mutation of global state that other functions might use.

If one argues that any global mutations are disallowed, regardless of whether they are observable or not, then no real life function can be considered pure ever, because any function would allocate its memory on stack, and allocation is impure, as it involves talking to MMU via OS, and allocated page might be residing in a different physical page, and so on, and so on.

So, why does this useless isolated `static int` makes function impure?

Comment: For example: Calling `f` often enough will result in an integer overflow and thus undefined behaviour if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: If `x` is truly isolated enough then `f` could be considered pure. But usually that means you don't actually need the variable.

Comment: @Mat It indeed is a global variable with a scope limited to only other instances of `f()`, making it unobservable by any other function (so they cannot change their behavior based on value of `x`). If no one sees this, it does not exist. If this is bad, why local variables (stack-allocated) do not violate purity? Local variables are also "global variables with limited scope" in some sense.

Comment: I think this question could be better phrased as "Why is it *useful* to consider this degenerate case of an impure function as impure?" Since we can't argue against the definition provided (the function mutates a local static variable. That's the definition. End of discussion).

Comment: @churill even if it's undefined behavior, it's natural that any function might occasionally explode due to halting problem (and "return" `⊥` as a result). For example, some pure function can have a stack allocated so large it will corrupt other's function stack without violating its purity.

Comment: The example is stripped down to highlight only this single aspect: mutation of a local static varible. Sloppy speaking "pure" means, the function is doing exactly the same for same input

Comment: At first guess, maybe it's defined this way because 1. making general and useful classifications of things is hard and 2. it's just easier to call any function that mutates a local static impure as a rule, and handle the strange exceptions where that local variable isn't used for anything as an exception that might warrant extra consideration

Comment: I guess if you're writing a paper on the subject, and you want to use the above function as an example of a pure function because its changed of internal state is totally decoupled from all other logical program flow, just be sure to provide that specific definition. I'm sure many academics would nod in agreement, while others would drop monocole/splash champagne/ruin ascot.

Comment: It's not clear what purpose `x` serves here, it's never exposed or accessible to other code. If somehow that *was* accessible then you'd have problems running this multi-threaded, `x++` is not atomic, which means it's arguably far from purely functional. One way to define pure functions is that they not share data between calls.

Comment: @John, in other words, is the Wikipedia article just wrong with this example due to oversimplifying things?

Comment: You might also be conflating the process of *preparing* a function call, such as in allocating memory on the stack if necessary, with *executing* a function call. Every program, pure functional or otherwise, has some kind of internal state or it'd be impossible to compute anything. Most functional programming languages do not consider the stack something to concern yourself with, it's an artifact of how the code is run and a limitation of Von-Neumann architectures. It may be possible to build a "functional" computer without that limitation.

Comment: @tadman if it was somehow accessible to any function other than `f()` in question, then `f()` wouldn't be pure with 100% certainty, because other functions _could_ theoretically change their behaviour based on `x` value even if they do not. But as it's not accessible, and it doesn't matter what `f()` is doing with `x` (computing `1000*x`th digit of π maybe in a multithreaded way?), as long as it's not visible anywhere, it's pure, isn't it?

Comment: If `x` is only manipulated and never accessed then it's a candidate for elimination by a sufficiently clever optimizing compiler. The question here is "Does `x` ever factor into any other computation?" and if not then `x` can be safely removed. If it can be removed then that function can be *made* purely functional, but it requires eliminating that term.

Comment: well, any clever compiler would remove `f()` altogether as well, because any pure `_ -> unit` is indistinguishable from just constant `unit`.

Comment: You may want to experiment with C++ compilers like `clang` to see what they do with full optimization enabled, plus what other functional languages like Haskell or Erlang do with the same function.

Comment: As for _preparing_ vs _executing_ - assigning local variables (which is commonly thought to preserve purity in imperative languages) changes global memory contents (accessible via impure means), so that's leaky abstraction anyway.

Comment: I'd be curious to know how everyone's interpretation of the purity of this function changes if it were replaced with an atomic variable with defined overflow.

Comment: @John Me too. Making it signed was probably an involuntary distraction. Sloppy Wiki example I guess.

Comment: For extra reading, the "talk" section of the wikipedia article is interesting. [talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Pure_function)

Comment: Oh dear. According to gcc, a [pure function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) is allowed to read global variables. Doesn't that allow the function to have different output for the same input? Or do we consider the global as input I suppose.

Comment: @John, I wouldn't take gcc's notion of pure functions into account... I guess they had to do it to make globally-configurable functions like `sin()` "kinda pure". Non-referentially transparent functions cannot be considered pure.

Comment: @toriningen it does matter how a compiler uses "pure", because I thought the question was whether the definition in the wikipedia article was correct or not. If the wikipedia article is ground truth, then your included function is impure. If the wikipedia article's definition is up for debate, then this question becomes, "What is the best definition for a pure function?" and one way to figure out the definition of a word is to see how it's used. I think in the end the result will be, "This function is academically pure but practically impure"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of a pure function is fully defined by its input arguments. Here, the result means not only the returned value, but also the effect in terms of the virtual machine defined by the C/C++ standard. In other words, if the function *occasionally* exhibits undefined behavior with the *same* input arguments, it cannot be considered pure (because the behavior is different from one call to another with the same input).

In the particular case with the static local variable, that variable may become the source of a data race if `f` is called concurrently in multiple threads. Data race means undefined behavior. Another possible source of UB is signed integer overflow, which may eventually happen.

Comment: I don't see how data race happens. Any change to `x` do not matter, regardless of whether computation was valid (`x` was incremented) or not (UB happened, `x` was incremented twice, etc.), because `f()` in it's form has no way to communicate contents of `x` to the caller, neither caller can read `x` in any way circumventing `f()`. And it's allowed for pure functions to _crash_ or _never return_, because there is valid term of `_ -> ⊥` like this `f = f ()`.

Comment: > Any change to x do not matter -- It does matter. A data race means the behavior is truly undefined. The implementation is allowed to crash or format your hard drive or whatever. Practically, a data race during increment may produce a trapping representation of `int`, which will signal and crash on the next call to `f`.

Comment: I disagree. If I have a function `int f(i) { return i + 1; }`, `i + 1` could overflow. Is this not pure? I would consider that function pure.

Comment: > And it's allowed for pure functions to crash or never return -- True, but *only consistently for the same input*. I.e. if it crashes for some input, it must crash every time for the same input, however and whenever you call the function.

Comment: @Ayxan the behavior (or undefined behavior) depends on the input, so it is pure. In the OPs case it depends on how often you call the function (for the overflow case).

Comment: @Ayxan Yes, your example is a pure function. The function in the original question is not, because it behaves *differently* from one call to another for the *same* input.

Comment: So, if there were no UB (because it would be `static unsigned int x`), then it becomes pure?

Comment: @AndreySemashev I had updated Wikipedia article and talk page using knowledge obtained from your answer.

Comment: > So, if there were no UB (because it would be `static unsigned int x`), then it becomes pure? -- If no UB (which means not only `unsigned int` but also atomic or mutex to synchronize concurrent access) then yes. That is, as long as `x` does not influence the function output, at which point `f` stops being pure. Which means `x` is rather useless.

Comment: @toriningen If your edit is the example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function#Pure_functions and its discussion, then the edit is wrong. That function is *not* pure, as is explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of pure functions seems to only matter in... functional languages? Correct me if I'm wrong. The wikipedia link you provide provides two references near the top, one of which is [Professor Frisby's Mostly Adequate Guide to Functional Programming](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/ch03.html#8th-grade-math). Where there are several different qualifications for a pure function, including:

> does not have any observable side effect

This matters because one of the things we can do to a pure function (as opposed to an impure function) is memoization (from the link above), or input/output caching. Pure functions are also testable, reasonable, and self documenting.

I guess memoization matters for the compiler, so asking if a function is "pure" *can* be considered equivalent to asking if the compiler can memoize the function. It seems like the concept of a `static` local variable that no other piece of code touches is just bad code, and the compiler should issue a warning about it. But should the compiler optimize it away? And should the compiler try to figure out if any given `static` local variable actually has no side effects?

It seems like it's just easier to design the compiler to always flag a function is impure if it has a `static` local, instead of writing logic to hem and haw over whether the function is memoizable or not. See a local `static`? Boom: no longer pure.

So from a compiler's point of view, it's impure.

What about the other properties of a pure function?

> testable, reasonable, and self documenting

Tests are written by a person, usually, so I'd argue this function is testable. Although some automated test-writing software might again see that it's not memoizable, and just choose to ignore writing tests for it entirely. This hypothetical software might just skip anything with local `static`s. Again, hypothetically.

Is the code reasonable? Certainly not. Although I'm not sure how much this matters. It doesn't *do* anything. It makes it hard to understand. ("Why did Bob write the function this way? Is this a Magic/More Magic situation?").

Is the code self-documenting? Again, I'd say not. But again, this is degenerate example code.

I think the biggest argument *against* this being considered a pure function is that a functional language compiler would be perfectly reasonable if it just assumed it wasn't pure.

I think the biggest argument *for* this being considered a pure function is that we can look at it with our own eyeballs and see that there's obviously no outside behavior. Ignore the fact that signed overflow is undefined. Replace this with a datatype that has defined overflow, and is atomic. Well now there's no undefined behavior, but it still *looks* weird.

"In conclusion, I don't care whether it's pure or not."

Let me rephrase from my previous (above) conclusion.

I'm inclined to just scan a function for any mutation of static variables and call it a day. Boom, no longer pure.

Can the function be considered pure if we really think about it? Sure. But what's the point? If the definition of a pure function needs to be changed, argue for it to be changed. Seems like you think this is a pure function. That's fine, I see the merits in that. I also see the merits in considering it an impure function.

As much as this is a non-answer, *it really depends* on what you're using the definition of *pure* for. If it's writing a compiler? Probably want to use the more conservative definition of pure that allows false positives and excludes this function. If it's to impress a bunch of sophomore CS students while listening to Zep? Go for the definition that recognizes this has no side effects and call it a day.

Comment: "I don't care whether it's pure or not." Well, _I do_. As for the properties you have described (like "self-documenting" and "reasonable"), those are fancy, but not really related to purity, because you cannot define those formally. Things like referential transparency can be though.

Comment: @toriningen we deal day-to-day with things that are not formally defined. That's the nature of life. If you want to write a paper where this very strict definition of pure matters, then call this function pure. If you want to *use* the definition of pure to do useful work, you probably need to relax it a little and just be okay with calling this function impure for the sake of going home at 5 o'clock.

Comment: i would rather say the opposite. The term "pure function" is defined such that it is practical. If the definition would say "Well pure means same output for same input" it would be useless, but having a precise definition of the term is what makes it useful